# How to convert a style transfer tensorflow model to mlmodel with flexible input shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, coremltools

I have read the Coreml guide which shows how to convert a pb model to mlmodel by using coremltools. However, I get the error below when trying to follow the guide. Which means the input shape must be specific.

> *ValueError: "ResizeBilinear" op: the second input, which is the output size, must be known statically*

So, have anyone know how to convert the flexible input shape mlmodel?

Here is my code:

```py
import coremltools as ct

def mlmodel_image(pb):
    input_shape = ct.Shape(shape=(1, ct.RangeDim(1, 720), ct.RangeDim(1, 1280), 3))
    model_input = ct.ImageType(shape=input_shape)
    mlmodel = ct.convert(pb, inputs=[model_input], source='TensorFlow')
    mlmodel.save(pb.replace(".pb", "_img.mlmodel"))
    print('------save to ', pb.replace(".pb", "_img.mlmodel"))
```

Comment: If the model in `.pb` file have specified input size and works only with it, there is no option to convert it into model with variable input size without making major changes inside model.

Comment: thnanks for your advice, but my .pb model have a flexible input size, any 4D shape is OK

Answer (score 0):

please try my sample:
https://github.com/dhrebeniuk/RealTimeFastStyleTransfer

And look my article with attached Google Colab Notebook in PyTorch.

There is instructions how run Style Transfer on iOS with maximum performance.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, while the ios engineer only accept the mlmodel